# Regular expression accepts all characters with at least five characters

Tags: regex

I've seen the following regular expression around the web.

```
(?=^.{8,}$)((?=.*\d)|(?=.*\W+))(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$
```

It validates only if the string:

- contain at least (1) upper case letter
- contain at least (1) lower case letter
- contain at least (1) number or special character
- contain at least (8) characters in length

But I am trying to make it contain at least 5 characters while allowing the user to use whichever characters they choose.

Comment: Then why do you need a regex?

Comment: No regex necessary here.  Just check that the string's length is >= 5 in whatever programming language you are using.

Comment: Please don't use annoying password restriction policies.

Comment: Thing is may need to update it from time to time so I am starting out with a broad regex that accepts everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression `.{5}` will match any string containing at least five characters. Note that, other than newlines, the characters can be *anything*, so a string consisting of five spaces will match.

Comment: No, the regular expression `.{5}` matches *exactly* five characters.  If you want more, use `.{5,}`.

Comment: ephemient: many regex implementations will accept a match anywhere in the target string. Unless the matching function implicitly anchors the search, `.{5}` will match any string with at least five characters.

Comment: @ephemient: tripleee is correct. I intentionally omitted the ^ and $ to get the shortest regex possible. `^.{5,}$` would of course work too.